# didSelectRowAtIndexpath not responding to clicks

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm making a revision app for high school students. In this view, the user should be able to select the units that they want to study for a certain subject, and the index path of the selected units will be stored in an int array and passed on to the next view for displaying images. Unfortunately, the `didSelectRowAt` method is not responding for some reason.

The delegate and data source are set correctly, I know that it is not getting called as I wrote a print statement in the function, and nothing was printed in the console when I click on any one the table cells.

```
var units = [String]()
var selectedRows = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return units.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "unitCell", for: indexPath) as! UnitCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = units[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)
    print(selectedRows)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination as! ImageView
    destination.folderNames = selectedRows
}
```

I expect an int array of row indexes of selected cells. But right now it is just empty.

Comment: Can you check if other delegate methods are getting called or not?

Comment: Yes they are, the cells are set up correctly, and an empty array is passed onto the next view through prepareforsegue @KeyurTailor

Comment: @TimmyMi how you are doing segue, can you show us the code.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati sorry, I'm new to stack overflow, how do I share code in the comment area?

Comment: @TimmyMi edit your answer would be good.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati done

Comment: @TimmyMi where are you setting tableView.delegate = self ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code your showing in your question is accurate, the signature of the `didSelectRowAt` method is incorrect. It should be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Note the leading "_" for the first parameter. If your class is a UITableViewController, you'll also need to add an `override` keyword.

If your code is already using this signature, please update your question to reflect that.

Also, this leading code cannot be correct. Please update it to what you're actually using,

`var units = String var selectedRows = Int`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview)

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Instead of your existing one

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Try and share your results.

Comment: Still nothing printed, I think the problem is that the method is not called when I click on my cell.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing is that your **didSectRow** is depricated so please use
  below one

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
  ```
- Secondly You have to set your TableView Delegate to Self like below

  ```
  tableView.delegate = self
  ```

Comment: @TimmyMi Ok sure, if you face any issue, do let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing printed or passed onto the next view.

Comment: Hmm... can you edit your question and show me the code of your controller where you added my instructions.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the code in my question, please check, thank you orz

Comment: @TimmyMi where are you initializing your selectedRows like var selectedRows = [Int]() ? .... I could not see it in your code